# Cant remove white margin between two divs

Tags: html, css

I have a parallax image setup above a div containg text with a gray background, but a white "margin" between the two divs wont go away.

```
<div class="parallax"></div>
<!-- KID START -->    

<div class="npa" style="height: 300px; background-color: #cccccc; margin-top: 0;">

    <h2 style="font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;">Confused Code Cat</h2>
    <p style="font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;">Confused Code Cat is Confused. Please Help.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `margin-top` from the `h2` tag, that is what creates the whitespace. like:

```
h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax"></div>
<!-- KID START -->    

<div class="npa" style="height: 300px; background-color: #cccccc; margin-top: 0;">

    <h2 style="font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;">Confused Code Cat</h2>
    <p style="font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;">Confused Code Cat is Confused. Please Help.</p>

</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, Saurav Rastogi fixed it. Thanks dude!

Comment: @ConfusedCodeCat It's my pleasure. Please upvote and accept this answer if this helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
h2 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, the `h2` margin is what is pushing the div down, but it might be desirable for you to keep that margin on the `h2` (why cramp your layout?). You can also add a padding to the `npa` div of 1px or larger. and keep the margin on the h2 element.

```
<div class="npa" style="height: 300px; background-color: #cccccc; padding: 1px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also reset the CSS using,

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax"></div>
<!-- KID START -->

<div class="npa" style="height: 300px; background-color: #cccccc; margin-top: 0;">

  <h2 style="font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;">Confused Code Cat</h2>
  <p style="font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;">Confused Code Cat is Confused. Please Help.</p>

</div>
```